# Swipe and change CIFilter - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer, cifilter

I would like to put a nice feature in my code.
I have a UIimage (capturedPhoto , which I took on a previous VC with a Camera module)

**I would like to swipe right/left and change filters to my capturedPhoto.**

The problems I have : With my code (see below), the resolution of the image change. I would like to maintain my original resolution.

My code :

on viewdidload

```
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PreviewController.swiped(gesture:)))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

and then I have a func to check the swipes

```
func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

            switch swipeGesture.direction {

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
                print("User Swiped Right")

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                print("User Swiped Left")

                let inputImage = capturedPhoto!
                let context = CIContext(options: nil)

                if let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir") {
                    let beginImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
                    currentFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                    currentFilter.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

                    if let output = currentFilter.outputImage {
                        if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
                            let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
                            // do something interesting with the processed image
                            self.ImageEdit.image = processedImage
                        } } }

            default:
                break
                  }}}
```

If someone could help me to :

1. fix the changing resolution (maintain my original one)
2. Swiping right (or left) would change the filter (so I guess I would need to list all the filters on an array?)

Many thanks !

Comment: One thing is missing in your question: Which CI filters are you using? Some of them - blurs and convolutions in particular - output a different image extent by definition. I found out today that the iBook I purchased in March 2016 is now free. I recommend that you get it: look for Core Image with Swift. It's Swift 2, but it will help you with this.

Comment: Hello @dfd ! I was thinking about 5/6 filters (classical ones- Effect Noir, Chrome..) 
In my code ,I only test one :"CIPhotoEffectNoir", but the idea could be to swipe left/right and have a loop of 4/5 classical filters

For eg  I found a list  filterNameList = ["No Filter" , "CIPhotoEffectFade", "CIPhotoEffectChrome", "CIPhotoEffectTransfer", "CIPhotoEffectInstant", "CIPhotoEffectMono", "CIPhotoEffectNoir", "CIPhotoEffectProcess", "CIPhotoEffectTonal"]

Comment: Well, your code looks correct to me. Maybe we're miscommunicating. What specifically do you mean by "resolution". If you compare the CIImage `extent` for the input and out, are they the same? The book I recommended... Chapter 3 addresses how to (a) process a filter and - on page 33 - (b) chain filters. One of them is CIPhotoEffectNoir. I *still* use this book, as he gets into creating custom filters and using Metal (not to be confused with Metal Performance Shaders) in later chapters.

Comment: For example, my original picture is in portrait. When it's processed by the filter, my final output shows me the filtered pictures in landscape.

Comment: I don't think that's the filter! I can think of two things. (1) The obvious one is the UIImageView's `contentMode`, which I believe you are aware of and shouldn't be the issue. The way to prove it is print to the console the input and output UIImage `size`, which should be the same as the CIImage `extent`. But... (2) if what you are saying is the image is *rotated*, that's an issue I have some code that can help. See my next comment.

Comment: Basically, the UIImageView "corrects" things - say you use the camera in landscape to take a picture. Now when you rotate your device and show it in an image view, it will appear properly oriented. However, the actual UIImage isn't. That is, the CIImage is oriented differently. And since your output image is oriented wrong also, when you create that CGImage it is oriented wrong also. Let me know if this is the case. If so, update your question a bit and I'll post some code that should help.

Comment: Thanks @dfd I’ll try this out !